# What about a fallback tag system or a groupped favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I like the notion of synonym tags but it would be great to have a fallback tag feature in stackoverflow.

This way, both `prestashop1.5` and `prestashop1.6` would fall back to `prestashop`.

For example, when browsing questions tagged `prestashop1.6` or `prestashop1.5`, a message would be displayed to browse the fallback tag which is `prestashop` and get a broader range of questions

Or even better, when a question is tagged `prestashop1.6` or `prestashop1.5`, the question will automatically be tagged `prestashop`.

**Edit:**
A better idea would be to have groupped favorite tags instead of just individual tags. That way, I can have a group which contains several variations and thus browse questions more easily

Comment: Oh, I just remembered, you can just follow `pretashop*` if you want to follow all of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a message letting me know about the other tags would be that bad, but I don't think we want to automatically include anything. Some people might be purposely avoiding the more general tag in favor of the more specific one, if they have a particular preference or expertise.

**Edit:**
You can follow `prestashop*` to browser all mentioned tags

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, I see the issue. I'll edit with a better idea